# What's the command for converting mp3 to ape using ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, mp3, ape

How to convert the mp3 music file to APE? It's easy to convert APE to mp3 but I have no idea to convert mp3 to APE.

Comment: How about you don't encode lossy data with a lossless compressor? you won't get back *ANY* quality, and when you inevitably convert it back to a lossy format again, it'll be even worse quality. you gain *NOTHING* by doing this, in fact it'll take up more space and sound worse.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, ffmpeg does not have a APE encoder.

http://www.monkeysaudio.com/links.html lists all the softwares that have encoding and playback capability.

If you are programmer then you can also download the SDK from the same website and use it in your program to create your own encoder.